# resize the height of Mat-form-field in Angular17

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular17

I'm trying to resize the height of `mat-form-field`, the outer border is changing, but the inside placeholder is not changing.

I'm using angular v17 and **Angular material 17.0.2**

trying to adjust the height of `mat-form-field`.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" >
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter name" >
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you want to do so I will try to give you the method to find it.

First, the documentation about [Angular input](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api) does not mention the possibility to change the height, so you will have to override the internal CSS, **which is often a hint that you are doing something wrong**

Open dev tools and inspect the element in order to find which element's style you want to override

[image]
[image]

Here, the height seems to be dictated by the `min-height` attribute on the class `mat-mdc-form-field-infix` so you will need to override it.

But as it is an internal class of `mat-input`, you will have to use `::ng-deep`.

**Beware** `::ng-deep` will cause anything you put in it to become a global style, so the style will "bleed" outside of your component and might affect other components of your application. Here, it might override the height of all components. To avoid that, you shall *always* include it in a `:host` element, like this :

```scss
:host { // Always protect ::ng-deep with a :host !
  ::ng-deep {
    .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
      min-height: 80px;
    }
  }
}
```

and voila :

[image]

Comment: You can use encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None to avoid [:ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)  =>  my-component-selector {
  .mat-mdc-form-field-infix {
    min-height: 80px;
  }